# In C++ get smallest integer type that can hold given amount of bits

Tags: c++, c++20, c++23

If I have compile time constant `num_bits` how can I get smallest integer type that can hold this amount of bits?

Of course I can do:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/5Pnc1xoPb)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>
std::size_t constexpr num_bits = 19;
using T =
    std::conditional_t<num_bits <=  8, uint8_t,
    std::conditional_t<num_bits <= 16, uint16_t,
    std::conditional_t<num_bits <= 32, uint32_t,
    std::conditional_t<num_bits <= 64, uint64_t,
        void>>>>;
```

But maybe there exists some ready made meta function in standard library for achieving this goal?

I created this question only to find out single meta function specifically from standard library. But if you have other nice suggestions how to solve this task besides my proposed above solution, then please post such solutions too...

---

**Update**. As suggested in comments, `uint_leastX_t` should be used instead of `uintX_t` everywhere in my code above, as `uintX_t` may not exist on some platforms, while `uint_leastX_t` always exist.

Comment: There is nothing ready-made I am aware of. But to strictly satisfy your requirement you should probably be using `std::uint_leastX_t` instead of `uintX_t`, or even better use the actual integer types instead of aliases, but then it becomes difficult to include extended integer types if there are any.

Comment: @user17732522 Can you please tell what's the difference between uint_least32_t and uint32_t? If "least" version can be sometimes 64-bit, then it is not what I want. Actually I want smallest integer that can hold given bits, not ANY, and not Fast, but smallest. Can uint32_t be ever non-32?

Comment: The `least` versions are the smallest integer type of at least that bit width. It could be e.g. that `uint_least16_t` is 24 bit wide if there is no 16 bit wide integer type (and in that case `uint16_t` doesn't exist). But as I said, probably checking against the bit widths of `char`, `short`, `int`, `long` and `long long` is a better approach to really get the smallest one. But that doesn't capture extended integer types if there are any (but then, neither are the fixed-size types guaranteed to capture that). All of this matters only if you want to support more exotic platforms.

Comment: There is also the issue that e.g. on typical desktop platforms `uint64_t` may be either `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` if both are 64 bit and then the question would be whether you want to guarantee that you choose the smaller rank, in which case `uint64_t` is unreliable and the bit widths of the integer types should be checked directly in order of rank.

Comment: You might also consider bit field or bit set if you want to optimize size.

Comment: The reason for using the `least` variations rather than the exact size variations is that the exact size variations might not exist; the `least` will always exist. For example, on a hardware platform that does't have 32-bit integers `uint32_t` won't exist, but `uint_least32_t` will.

Comment: @PeteBecker BTW, is there any special reason why alias type `uint_least24_t` doesn't exist and other multiples of 8 too? Only 8/16/32/64 exist as I see, at least after experimenting in godbolt.

Comment: @Arty -- nothing beyond the obvious fact that sizes other than powers of 2 tend to not exist. I don't think there's a deep reason for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no template type for this in the c++ standard library.

<sup><sub>The standard library *does* have something to do the *reverse* of what you're looking for ([`std::numeric_limits<T>::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max)).</sub></sup>

There is a proposal to add such functionality to the c++ standard library in [p0102: "*C++ Parametric Number Type Aliases*"](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0102r0.html). A similar question to yours has been asked [on lists.isocpp.org/std-proposals](https://lists.isocpp.org/std-proposals/2019/06/0064.php), where p0102 was mentioned.

In case you're interested in / okay with using [Boost](https://www.boost.org/), Boost has [`boost::int_max_value_t<V>`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/integer.html), which is a struct defining type members `least` (smallest) and `fast` ("easiest to manipulate").

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no ready made meta function for this